# Where do the notes synchronized from the iPad go?

Tags: ipad, apple-notes

I synchronize e-mails, contacts, calendar and notes between my iPad and Google. Google has web interfaces for the first three, but where do my notes end up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notes that you sync with Google will show up in Gmail in your archive as messages from you with the label `Notes`.

You can get to them by choosing the label `Notes` from Gmail's left side nav bar (you'll have to click on the "n `more`" down-arrow first if you have a bunch of labels already).

Comment: Now that I know that, i just have to ask; How do I edit the notes from Gmail?

Comment: @Hubro, it seems that iOS is kind of "hacking" Gmail for this functionality.  My guess is, when we edit a note on our iPads, it makes a copy of what's already there, and then when we save it again, it replaces the old copy with the updated version.  So, the closest thing we would be able to do in Gmail, is to "forward" the "note" (actually an archived Gmail message) to ourselves, and edit the forwarded version, then send it and when we "receive" it, apply the "Notes" label to it, and delete the old version.

Comment: @Baodad Pretty old question, but I think that's what I did